# In a bash script, can i use && to group two command line arguments together

Tags: bash, scripting

Here is a snippet:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ $arg == "--coverage" ]; then
        ENABLE_COVERAGE=1
        shift
    elif [ $arg == "--mysql" ]; then
        MYSQL_ONLY=1
        shift
    elif [ $arg == "--psql" ]; then
        PSQL_ONLY=1
        shift
    elif [ $arg == "-h" ] || [ $arg == "--help" ]; then
        usage
        shift
    elif [ $arg == "--qa" ]; then
        QA_ONLY=1
        PSQL_ONLY=1
        MYSQL_ONLY=1
        shift
   elif [ $arg == "--qa" ] && [ $arg == "--mysql" ]; then
        QA_ONLY=1
        MYSQL_ONLY=1
        shift
   elif [ $arg == "--qa" ] && [ $arg == "--psql" ]; then
        QA_ONLY=1
        PSQL_ONLY=1
        shift
    elif [ $arg == "--" ]; then
        shift 
        break                                               
    fi                                                      
done
```

Comment: I want to group two command line arguments in bash, so can i use the && operator like:  elif [ $arg == "-h" ] || [ $arg == "--help" ]; then
        usage
        shift

Comment: You know you can do this too: `elif [ $arg == "-h" -o $arg == "--help" ]` and `elif [ $arg == "--qa" -a $arg == "--mysql" ]`. That might make it a bit clearer what you want to do. And, yes you can and both tests with `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can call getopt in bash, you can't call getopt, it shouldn't use long option name. use getopts instead of getopt.(below is a example)

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts qm OPT
do
  case $OPT in
    q) opt_qa=1;;
    m) opt_mysql=1;;
  esac
done

if [ $opt_qa = 1 ]; then
  # do as qa
fi

if [ $opt_mysql = 1 ]; then
  # do as mysql
fi
```

Comment: both options are grouped, so they have to treated together (i added more code, hope that helps)

Comment: elif [ $arg == "--qa" ] && [ $arg == "--mysql" ]; then
seem to be working, but i wanted to verify, if i can group together arguments like this, if anyone had experience doing that.

Comment: @kamal: We keep telling you.  $arg cannot be equal to both --qa and --mysql AT THE SAME TIME.  $arg might be those two values at different times, but that is a different test entirely (when you detect the first, save that state and later when you detect the second, see if the first was detected).

Comment: Thanks finally got it, took a while though.

Answer (score 1):

`$arg` can *never* be equal to `--qa` and `--mysql` at the same time.

If you're talking about *different* arguments then yes, you can do something like this:

```
if [[ $arg1 == "--qa" && $arg2 == "--mysql" ]] ; then
    QA_ONLY=1
    MYSQL_ONLY=1
fi
```

But I often find it's a better idea to just scan the arguments sequentially setting a flag for each one, then using the flags to decide behaviour. Otherwise you're either limiting your command line arguments to a specific order (`xyz --qa --mysql` will work but `xyz --mysql -- qa` won't) or your code becomes hideously complicated since it's trying to check *every* argument against *every* possibility.

Comment: --qa and --psql are seperate arguments

Comment: i am using @$ (have added more code in the question) , $arg1 and $arg2 would not hold in this , correct ?